# how to make fbox produce similar result to boxed from amsmath when used inside display math?

Tags: framed

I use Scientific word to generate Latex, and from its GUI, it only supports `\fbox` to put a frame around a displayed equation.  i.e. I select the equation from the GUI and click on a button which adds a frame. The latex it generates adds `fbox` inside `\[...\]` and so I have no control over this.

What I can do is add something in the preamble of the latex file that can fix or improve something it does.

The problem is that `\fbox` seems to change the size of the math on the right side of the equation compared to the left side. When I do the same thing using `\boxed` I get much better result, which is what I want. (but again, the GUI generates `\fbox` and there is no way to tell SW to use `boxed` instead).

Here is a MWE and it is clear that `fbox` output is not right.

At first I thought if I make the `fboxsep` larger that will fix it, but that has no effect at all on the font size. Is there something else I can add to preamble to make the result look like `\boxed`?

One last thing, I can't just change `\fbox` by `\boxed` using some smart text replacement macro, as SW will not longer be able to display the equation on the screen then, since it does not know what `\boxed` is.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}
\begin{document}

\[
\fbox{$x_1\left(  t\right)  =x_{20}\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(
1+t^2\right)  }}$}%
\]

\[
\boxed{x_1\left(  t\right)  =x_{20}\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(
1+t^2\right)  }}}%
\]

\end{document}
```

Result is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: A side remark: The code for the equation is not very; I would write it as `\[\fbox{$x_1(t) = x_{20} \frac{t}{1 + t^{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + t^{2}}}$}\]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to explicitly switch to `\displaystyle` within `\fbox`. This way, the `\[...\]` can be omitted, unless it should be centered explicitly (well use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` or `\centering` (grouped!))

I added a command `\mathfbox` which does the `\[...\]` and the displaystyle automatically.

All three ways are shown in the screen shot. The `\mathfbox` output is the middle one!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}

\newcommand{\mathfbox}[1]{%
  \[%
  \fbox{%
    \ensuremath{\displaystyle{#1}}%
  }% End of \fbox
  \]%
}%


\begin{document}

\[
\fbox{%
$\displaystyle x_1\left(  t\right)  =x_{20}\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(
1+t^2\right)}}$}%
\]


\mathfbox{x_1\left(  t\right)  =x_{20}\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+t^2\right)}}}%

\[
\boxed{x_1\left(  t\right)  =x_{20}\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(
1+t^2\right)  }}}%
\]

\end{document}
```

This way both boxes look the same ... I suspect, that `\boxed` is doing nothing different than `\fbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle...}`

[image]

### Update, with redefined `\fbox` command

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% 
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}
\begin{document}


\LetLtxMacro\LaTeXStandardFBox\fbox


\renewcommand{\fbox}[1]{%
  \LaTeXStandardFBox{%
    \expandarg
    \StrSubstitute[1]{#1}{$}{$\displaystyle}%
  }% End of \fbox
}%

\[
\fbox{$x_1\left(  t\right)  =x_{20}\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+t^2\right)}}$}%
\]

\let\fbox\LaTeXStandardFBox%
\[
\boxed{x_1\left(  t\right)  =x_{20}\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(
1+t^2\right)  }}}%
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to write some macro in preamble to do this? i.e. without having to edit the generated code itself? I can't edit the code generated each time and fix this by hand as I mentioned I use SW GUI to generate this code and it is not practical to edit this each time I make changes. Also SW does not understand this new code any more and so it does not display correctly on the screen any more. Here is screen shot from SW to explain the issue ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zmrZt.png)

Comment: @Nasser: See my update

Comment: Thanks again. But I do not think I explained my problem well. I can't add \mathfbox from the GUI. So I have no way to use it when using SW. The issue is that SW generates the `fbox` and I can only add code to preamble to fix things, but can't edit the code or add code inside the document, since SW will not understand it if it does not supports it in the GUI. The fix has to be to do it all in the preamble only. This way I can still use the GUI but get the correct output when I compile. I hope this explain the problem better.

Comment: Why don't you add `\mathfbox` to the preamble????

Comment: I can add `\mathfbox` to preamble. But this is not the issue. How would I tell SW to use it? I click on a button to add frame around equation. SW generates `\fbox`. Now what? I can't tell SW to generate code that uses `\mathfbox` instead. Is there a way to redefine fbox itself to make it do `\ensuremath{\displaystyle` ? So I do not have to edit the code. Your answer is useful and I can use it when writing direct Latex. But I am using SW at this moment.

Comment: I have never used SW (I don't know even the link to it), but I have known this issue, I would not answered it. The question developped to be `off-topic`, I fear

Comment: SW can be removed completely out of the picture. The problem is this: Is there a way to make `fbox` behave the same as `boxed` without modifying the code itself, but only using the preamble? That is all. I can add any code to the preamble, but can't edit the code itself or add extra code inside.

Comment: @Nasser: See the update

Comment: THanks again, but it does not work on the code generated. You removed the $$ from the code that was there. Here is MWE again. I get errors compiling this: 
`\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}

\LetLtxMacro\LaTeXStandardFBox\fbox

\renewcommand{\fbox}[1]{%
  \[%
  \LaTeXStandardFBox{%
    \ensuremath{\displaystyle{#1}}%
  }% End of \fbox
  \]%
}%

\begin{document} %can't modify code below
\[
\fbox{$x_1\left(  t\right)  =x_{20}\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(
1+t^2\right)  }}$}%
\]
\end{document}`
if you need clarifications, I am in chat.

Answer (score 5):

As usual my advice is to drop front ends to LaTeX if they don't support basic constructions and, like SW, are based on older TeX distributions.

The solution I'll suggest is a hack that will possibly give bad results in other situations. Also, `\boxed` should be used ***very*** sparingly in general (“never” is a good approximation to “very sparingly”).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\latexfbox\fbox
\renewcommand{\fbox}[1]{%
  \latexfbox{\everymath{\displaystyle}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\fbox{$x_1\left(  t\right)  =x_{20}\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(
1+t^2\right)  }}$}%
\]

\[
\boxed{x_1\left(  t\right)  =x_{20}\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(
1+t^2\right)  }}}%
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution worked very well also. SW is able to read the latex file ok and display frame on screen since the internal code was not changed and kept as is. Only preamble changed which is ok.